# How to target <a> tag

Tags: html, css

How to make such a reference or correct the alignment and underline links?

```
<body>
<div class="div1">
    <a href="http://">
    <div><div class="div2">very long text very long text very long text</div><span>(0/1)</span></div>
</a>
</div>
```

```
.div1
{
    width:200px;
}
.div2
{   display:inline-block;
    width:140px;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C76F7/1/

I need using text-overflow:ellipsis in reference.

Comment: Don't put `div` into `a`. You should never insert block elements into inline elements.

Comment: @Brewal Really? Why not?

Comment: @Brewal its fine in HTML5..

Comment: @billy its was invalid in HTML 4 and before..

Comment: Do you just want to use text, or do you want to style the whole package? (background, height, width, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I'd recommend you consider why you're attempting this and whether there are any other approaches. The below is a fairly dirty way of accomplishing it however. As long as `a` has a width set, the content should then scale as appropriate.

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/C76F7/3/)

HTML

```
 <a href="http://">
        <div>very long text very long text very long text</div><div>(0/1)</div>
    </a>
```

CSS

```
a {
    display:table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    width:200px;
}
a div {
    display:table-cell;
}
a div:first-child {
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
a div:last-child {
    width:35px;
}
```

**Update**

An alternative may be to simply use:

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/C76F7/4/)

HTML

```
 <a href="http://">
        <div>(0/1)</div>very long text very long text very long text
    </a>
```

CSS

```
a {
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px;
    padding-right:35px;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    position:relative;
}
a div {
    position:absolute;
    left:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here use this

```
.div2
{   display:inline-block;
    width:140px;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-decoration:underline;//for underline
    vertical-align:middle;//for vertical alignment
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```